# How to search through a 2d list and prints the location (x, y)

Tags: python

I have this problem in my python class. I have to loop through a 2d list of items and print what is found and in what location (x, y).

Output that I should get:

```
In square (1, 0) we found apple
In square (4, 0) we found lion
In square (1, 1) we found kobra
In square (2, 1) we found cat
In square (3, 1) we found kobra
In square (0, 2) we found hyena
In square (2, 2) we found apple
In square (3, 2) we found kobra
```

The code I have so far:

```
ITEMS = {
    "a": "apple",
    "k": "kobra",
    "@": "cat",
    "h": "hyena",
    "l": "lion"
}
def inspect_square(square, y, x):
    while True:
        if square == "a":
            print("In square ({}, {}) we found {}".format(x, y, ITEMS[square]))
        elif square == "k":
            print("In square ({}, {}) we found {}".format(x, y, ITEMS[square]))
        elif square == "@":
            print("In square ({}, {}) we found {}".format(x, y, ITEMS[square]))
        elif square == "h":
            print("In square ({}, {}) we found {}".format(x, y, ITEMS[square]))
        elif square == "l":
            print("In square ({}, {}) we found {}".format(x, y, ITEMS[square]))
        else:
            continue


def search_field(field):
    for y in field:
        for x in y:
            inspect_square(square, y, x)



field = [
    [" ", "a", " ", " ", "l"],
    [" ", "k", "@", "k", " "],
    ["h", " ", "a", "k", " "]
]


search_field(field)
```

I get error message that square is not defined but I'm not sure if that's the main problem in my work so far. It might be a simple fix, but I can't see it. How can I continue? Is there a mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Added traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Downloads\pelto.py in <module>
     36
     37
---> 38 search_field(field)

~\Downloads\pelto.py in search_field(field)
     25     for y in field:
     26         for x in y:
---> 27             inspect_square(square, y, x)
     28
     29

NameError: name 'square' is not defined
```

Comment: You could add a copy of the traceback’ in order to help readers.

Comment: traceback added

Comment: what is `square`?

Comment: square is just one of the possible locations for an item on the list

Answer (score 1):

You get the error when calling the `inspect_square`. Because you call it with `square` which is not defined.

Another solution

```
for y, line in enumerate(field):
    for x, item in enumerate(line):
        if item != " ":
            print("In square ({}, {}) we found {}".format(x, y, ITEMS[item]))
```